# Is correct to use square icons on iOS?

Tags: ios, icons

Let me explain, these are the names and size of the icons that I use currently for developing an app for iOS (with titanium appcelerator , but this is not important)

[image]

Previously I used recognizable icons with rounded edges, but now I insert the icons with the rectangular shape for comfort.

I just wanted to know if this could be a problem in displaying the icon of the app on the device. The icon of the app in the Springboard is automatically rounded, as well as in the settings of the device. I wanted to know if this rounding automatic, happen in all positions where the icon appears, thanks

Answer (score 9):

### Yes.

This is how you're supposed to do it. iOS automagically rounds the corners, as you say.

In fact, you shouldn't be rounding the corners yourself. If iOS were to change how corners are rounded in a future release, your icon might look rather ugly with white/black 'fragments' near the corners.

There's a neat exploration of the iOS 7 corner rounding changes [here](http://www.mani.de/backstage/?p=483) - this is the diff between iOS 6 rounding and iOS 7 rounding:

[image]

Comment: This is documented in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html): “Make sure your icon has 90° corners so it looks good after the mask is applied.”

Comment: Yes, yes, I knew that from iOS to iOS 6 7 corners of the icons have changed, I just wanted to know if you create square icons was the right solution, thanks to all